# The SDK Build Tools revision (23.0.1) is too low for project ':app'. Minimum required is 25.0.0

Tags: android-studio, sdk

I have been stuck in a problem.. Its been probably 3 hours..
     In android studio message says.

```
Error: The SDK Build Tools revision (23.0.1) is too low for project ':app'. Minimum required is 25.0.0
Install Build Tools 25.0.0, update version in build file and sync ..
```

But the version 25.0.0 is not available when i went for update...

Answer (score 0):

Build Tools 25.0.0 is available ,may something  wrong for your IDE ,restart your IDE Or reinstall your IDE .

Answer (score 0):

Try to check here https://github.com/oblador/react-native-keychain/issues/68#issuecomment-304836725
It helped me, but I faced a little bit other issue: “The SDK Build Tools revision (23.0.1) is too low for project ‘:{project_name}’. Minimum required is 25.0.0”